# Bounding the solution of a logarithmic equation

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, lambert-w

Given a small number $\varepsilon >0$ and a constant $1/3\le \alpha < 1 $, I am looking for the smallest possible number $x^*$ such that for all real $x\ge \max\{x^*,3\}$, we have
$$\frac{x}{(\log x)^{\alpha}} \ge \varepsilon^{-2\alpha}. \tag1$$

Equivalently, the quantity I am looking for is (an upper bound of) the solution of the above equation with the $``\ge" $ symbol replaced by $``="$, but my understanding is that the equation is not tractable (WolframAlpha is also clueless), and I am not sure of how to find bounds for the solution. For instance, when I look for candidates of the form $x^*\equiv\varepsilon^\beta$, I end up having to solve $(\log\varepsilon)^{-\alpha}\ge\beta^\alpha\varepsilon^{-2\alpha-\beta}$ for $\beta$, which does not seem easier.

Since for the values of $x$ and $\alpha$ I'm considering, we have $(\log x)^{-\alpha}\ge(\log x)^{-1}$, I decided instead to let $M\equiv\varepsilon^{-2\alpha} $ and look for the solution of the easier equation
$$ \frac{x}{\log x} \ge M\tag2$$
For which [WolframAlpha tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%2Flog%28x%29+%3D+t+for+x) the solution is given by
$$x^* = \exp(-W(-1/M)) = \exp(-W(-\varepsilon^{2\alpha})) \tag3 $$
where $W$ is [Lambert's $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (not sure how that result is derived btw).

To finish, I just need a good upper bound on $x^*$ above but 1) I am not really familiar with the $W$ function and, searching online, I can't find good bounds in the interval $[-1/e,0[ $, and 2) the solution $(3)$ is suspicious : as $\varepsilon\to 0$, the solution $x^*$ should diverge, but according to $(3)$, $x^*$ converges to $0$ ! I am not sure of what went wrong, and the mistake probably comes from my lack of understanding of the $W$ function.

Hence, I ask **can anyone give an estimate of the smallest solutions of $(1)$ and/or $(2)$ in terms of $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ and  $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ ?** I'd prefer avoiding the use of Lambert's function, if possible.

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y := x^{1/\alpha}$.
The condition is written as: for all $y^\alpha \ge \max(x^\ast, 3)$,
$$\frac{y^\alpha}{(\alpha \ln y)^\alpha} \ge \varepsilon^{-2\alpha}$$
or
$$\frac{y}{\ln y} \ge \frac{\alpha}{\varepsilon^2}. \tag{1}$$

Note that $\frac{y}{\ln y} \ge \frac{3^{1/\alpha}}{\ln 3^{1/\alpha}}$ on $y \ge 3^{1/\alpha}$. If $\frac{\alpha}{\varepsilon^2}\le \frac{3^{1/\alpha}}{\ln 3^{1/\alpha}}$, then (1) is true for all $y\ge 3^{1/\alpha}$ (thus, $x^\ast = -\infty$).
In the following, assume that
$\frac{\alpha}{\varepsilon^2} > \frac{3^{1/\alpha}}{\ln 3^{1/\alpha}}$ (in this case, $x^\ast > 3$).
The condition (1) is equivalent to
$$y \ge - \frac{\alpha}{\varepsilon^2} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{\alpha}\right)$$
where $W_{-1}(\cdot)$ is the second branch of the Lambert W function. Thus,
$$x^\ast = \left(- \frac{\alpha}{\varepsilon^2} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{\alpha}\right)\right)^{\alpha}.$$